# jQuery jCarousel - how to remove the jCarousel from an element

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I am using jCarousel to have a carousel of images in my page.  It works great and I have no complaints, but I am using the tabbing on the page and when I go to another tab, there is an ugly jCarousel error. Basically what I want to do is to remove the jCarousel from my element when I go to a new tab but for the life of me can't figure it out.

To add the carousel I am using code like this:

```
$("#myelement").jCarousel({ /* config params */});
```

But I am unsure of how to remove `.jCarousel` from `$("#myelement")`. Any ideas?

Comment: when you go to your new tab just change the id of your element on which jCarousel is applied.

Answer (score 1):

If need only to remove jCarousel, you can use destroy method
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/api.html#destroy

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a remove function as part of the plugin.

You could dig into the source and build one, or a quicker mechanism may be to clone `myelement`, remove the element and then replace with the cloned version.

Answer (score 0):

[Removing an item from jCarousel plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645980/removing-an-item-from-jcarousel-plug-in/4713536#4713536)

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is currently broke in jcarousel. The remove method exists but does not provide the desired result. An issue was submitted here:

https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/338

As a workaround, none of which work correctly without breaking the carousel see the discussion here:

[Removing an item from jCarousel plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645980/removing-an-item-from-jcarousel-plug-in)

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this as it is a horrible solution :P :

You could hide the carousel using CSS and then use .hide and .show based on what tab you are on.

$("#myelement #yourcarouselIDorClass").hide()