# Removing items from jCarousel by index

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Is it possible to remove items by index from jCarousel ? Thank you,

Comment: Do you mean this jCarousel? http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645980/removing-an-item-from-jcarousel-plug-in

Answer (score 0):

Replace 2 with a Index variable you want to remove.

$('.jcarousel-item-2').remove();

Tested [here](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_callbacks.html) in console.